# How to get information from xml using ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml

Here is my XML

```
<resultitem>
<itemname>Restaurant</itemname>
<address>Some Road</address>
<rating>4</rating>
</resultitem>
<resultitem>
<itemname>Cafe</itemname>
<address>Some street</address>
<rating>3</rating>
</resultitem>
```

I want to get the rating of the restaurant. How do I do that?

Here is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    url:'someurl',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml){
         $(xml).find('resultitem').filter(function(){
         var name = $(this).find('itemname').text()==Cafe;
         alert(name);
         });
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML needs to be wrapped in order to find `<resultitem>` elements.

```
jQuery('<wrapperElement>' + xml + '</wrapperElement>').find('resultitem itemname:contains("Cafe")').each(function(){
     var rating = $(this).parent().find('rating').text()
     alert(rating);
     });
```

Comment: I found it: <PlaceSearchResponse><root><resultitem>.....</resultitem></root></PlaceSearchResponse>